# how to extract string from in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given string is like `const testString = 'hello people, @ppshein1@gmail.com @ppshein2@gmail.com';`

But I want to convert like `['@ppshein1@gmail.com', '@ppshein2@gmail.com']` and do like that:

```
function getString() {
  const str = 'hello people, @ppshein1@gmail.com @ppshein2@gmail.com';
  var n = str.slice(str.indexOf('@'), str.length);
  var arr = n.split(' ');
  return arr;
}
```

I feel it's not best practice to develop and no error handling as well. Could you guy suggest me how to improve to meet es6 syntax for above my code and be best practice. Thanks.

Comment: will it always have gmail ids? I don't think so.. would there any comma `,` within the email ids part?

Comment: That looks pretty good to me - just first check that `@` exists and that there is text after it.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo seems to be email id, but there is no comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look for `@` and not whitespace.

```js
var string = 'hello people, @ppshein1@gmail.com @ppshein2@gmail.com';

console.log(string.match(/@\S+/g));
```